# Clustering methods ⊂ Unsupervised learning

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning, model-based-clustering

Is it proper to say that clustering methods are mostly unsupervised learning techniques, with some exceptions such as model-based clustering?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. On the other hand, can we consider model-based clustering as supervised learning? (In this context, the data would be "labelled" by introducing the likelihood of belonging to a certain multivariate distribution, which corresponds to a cluster.)

Answer (score 3):

Clustering is sub-class of unsupervised learning.
Unsupervised learning techniques include clustering, feature extraction (e.g., PCA, Isomap, KODAMA), and feature selection (e.g., selection the variables with highest variance value).
I think model-based clustering methods are still unsupervised techniques. 
Although you decide the model what you want, you do not use the information about the labels.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, clustering is unsupervised, with the exception if semi-supervised clustering, where parts of the data are labeled.

Answer (score 0):

Dimensionality reduction is typically done unsupervised. However, unfortunately, I have seen the term unsupervised learning used synonymously with clustering way too frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Clustering is generally unsupervised, but there are many other unsupervised learning techniques that are not clustering, per se, for instance the learning of self-organizing feature maps.